# Issues linking HTML with stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues linking my external stylesheet `style.css` with my HTML file `index.html`.

The tree in which these files are stored looks as follows:

`+--- templates
 |    |
 |    +--- index.html
 +--- static
     |
     +--- style.css`

Inside my HTML file `index.html` i make use of `LINK` to grab the stylesheet `style.css`.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/style.css">
</head>
```

And `style.css` looks like this :

```
body{
    background: blue;
    color: yellow;
    padding:1%
}

.button {
    font: bold 15px Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Unfortunately when i load up `index.html` on my browser under my IP address (hosted by lighttpd) the stylesheet is not linked and the page remains white, instead of turning blue with yellow text as it should.  I have researched similar questions and tried a few things out however i still cannot find a way to link them, can anyone shed some light on the situation?

EDIT:
If i double click on `index.html` from the directories to open it up as a webpage then the stylesheet successfully links and the page is blue.  However if I access the page via my IP address in the browser the same page loads but in plain old white.  So i guess the stylesheet is linking properly it is more an issue with the file i am passing through lighttpd??

Comment: Have you looked at the developer tools in your browser? Any errors in the console? Does the network tab show the stylesheet loading?

Comment: should work the way it's presented in the question. Check for typos, correct filepaths etc.

Comment: @j08691 - How can i check these? Sorry i am fairly new to all of this, thanks for your help.

Comment: body{padding:1%} is missing a semicolon ; maybe thats it, because path seems correct

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox you can press F12 to open the tools

Comment: @JulianEspinosa the last rule does not require `;`

Comment: ah okay, I am using chromium on Raspberry Pi! @j08691

Comment: @Huangism shish I didn't knew that.. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Johannes - Iv edited my question with some more information

Comment: What URL are you using to see index.html? If you've configured your lighttpd to use "Templates" as its root, you're not going to get the css to load. Also, if you're using a template system, the link must reference the css in relation to the rendered template.

Comment: "if I access the page via my IP address..." - do you maybe have another copy of that file in another directory which you are acidentially opening when using your IP adress`? (i.e. are you actually including the "templates" folder in that address?)

Comment: @Paurian I see what you mean, I am in fact using templates as the root in lighttpd config file, the reason being is because I'm using flask to send data to the HMTL page and this requires the templates / static directories tree. Thanks

Comment: @Paurian - why is it that if I use templates as the root that it won't load the css? I thought the href directs it into the static folder to find the css?

Comment: Templates could render through the server (like old-style shtml files of the 90's) that change their relative location TO THE BROWSER. That means the browser doesn't see the http://localhost/templates/index.html path, but the http://localhost/index.html path. This would then change the relative location of the static folder, if it's exposed by the server at all. // Are you able to go to http://localhost/static/style.css and download that file through your browser (provided the http server has permissions that allow it)?

Answer (score 0):

Well your code is totally correct when you run it on browser do right click and in pop menu select view page source when your code show open your style link and see if it is open in the browse or not if its open in browser then this means that your stylesheet is linked.